# Access server on secondary LAN-to-WAN subnet from the main subnet in a cascaded network

Tags: port-forwarding, node.js, ubuntu-16.04, static-routes, ipfilter

I want to access my server on a different subnet.

Here is my network topology:

```
    Internet
        |  
        | 
       ADSL 
    x.x.x.x (external)
   D-link DSL-2730E (Router1)---------------------+
    255.255.255.0                                 |
    192.168.1.1 (internal)                        |
      DHCP active                                 |
        |                                         |
        |                                         |
        |                                         |
    LAN-to-WAN                                    |
    192.168.1.2 (external, static)          192.168.1.100 (DHCP)
    Linksys WAG120N (Router2)                 PC1 Windows 10
    255.255.255.0                        
    192.168.2.1 (internal)
      DHCP active
        |
        |                             
    192.168.2.2 (static)          
    Ubuntu Server 16.04 with node server listening on Port 3344
```

Additional info:

- Router1 is connected to Router2 LAN-to-WAN
- Both routers is NAT-enabled, dynamic routing disabled
- Router2 SPI firewall protection switched off, unblocked anonymous WAN request
- Router1 port forwarding to 192.168.1.2 WAN port 3344, LAN port 3344 TCP
- Router2 port forwarding to 192.168.2.2 WAN port 3344, LAN port 3344 TCP
- I can ping Router2 192.168.2.1 from my PC1
- I get "Request timed out" when I ping the server 192.168.2.2 from my PC1
- I have set up a static route on my Router1 with destination to 192.168.2.0, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, next-hop address 192.168.1.2, there is only one interface available which is a1 interface and the metric to 1.
- The port forwarding is working and the server is responding when the traffic is coming from the internet i.e. when I enter the Router1 external IP address and the forwarded port x.x.x.x:3344 in a browser on PC1, I get a response in the browser. Strangely, when I enter Router2 external IP address 192.168.1.2:3344 or Router2 internal IP address 192.168.2.1:3344 (via static route) in the browser on PC1 which I expect the Router2 to forward the traffic to my server@192.168.2.2:3344, neither of them works, on Google Chrome it says "This site can’t be reached".
- You may ask why I am not using the LAN port instead of WAN port on my Router2. My goal is to block internet access completely for the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet and to allow internet access for the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.
  There will be about 12 android client devices connecting to the server in the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet which are not allowed to access the internet except the server.
- Another reason I want to use a separate subnet is because it will be easier to manage the internet access filter by filtering the whole IP range (except the server) in the subnet through a single router.

Here is my tracert result from PC1:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.2.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     3 ms     4 ms     2 ms  192.168.2.1

Trace complete.

Tracing route to 192.168.2.2 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        2 ms  192.168.1.2
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

It doesn't seem like a router issue to me, where does it go wrong, the Ubuntu or the node/express server? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

- Swapped the routers
- Disabled NAT and port forwarding on Router2
- Router1 port forwarding to 192.168.2.2 WAN port 3344, LAN port 3344 TCP, I still can access the server from my public IP:3344, but cannot access the server from my router1 IP:3344

Comment: You can still add firewall rules to router 1 and have it take care of the separation you are planning to implement with this double NAT. NAT always adds useless complexity.

Comment: The first router will need to know how to reach the network behind the second router. Routers learn routes in three ways: directly connected networks, statically configured routes, or through a dynamic routing protocol. The network behind the second router must either be statically configured on the first router, or you need to run a routing protocol between the routers so that the second router can tell the first router about any networks it has.

Comment: @Ron I have set up a static route on my Router1 as above.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen If I am having double NAT, then why I can still access the port from the internet?

Comment: Updated my setting: disabled double NAT

Answer (score 1):

Delete your double NAT. It will cause confusion and break things. Especially with consumer gear not designed for this use case.

Add a router and firewall capable of VLANs and multiple subnets at your Internet edge. Firewall your restricted subnet to not have Internet. Add DHCP service and wireless APs in the restricted subnet as desired.

Comment: Which better router should I get? Any recommendation?

Comment: I have disabled the Router2 NAT but still no luck.

Comment: Hello John, may I know what is the feature should I be looking for in the router to make it work? Thank you.